# How to download and install ansible modules?

Tags: ansible

I have found this DNSimple ansible module:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dnsimple_module.html

but can not find anywhere on that page to download and install it? How do I go about downloading and installing ansible modules like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module itself is part of ansible since version 1.6 (as stated [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dnsimple_module.html)). To use it, you need to have `dnsimple` on your host machine (also stated in the above description). Install it with `sudo pip install dnsimple`

Comment: can you do that without using `pip` as well? if so, how?

Comment: Looks like it was: `ansible-galaxy collection install [collecetion.name]`

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer solved the questioner's problem but didn't address the broader scope of the question.

How to install an Ansible module? The documentation is currently vague as to how to achieve this simple requirement!

An excellent general guide to writing modules (I've no connection to the author) can be found [here](http://blog.toast38coza.me/custom-ansible-module-hello-world/).

The quickest way is to simply have a folder called library/ in the same folder as your playbook. Inside this folder, place the python script for the Ansible Module. You should now have a corresponding task available to your playbook.

If you want to share your module across multiple projects, then you can add an entry to `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` pointing to a shared library location, eg:

```
library        = /usr/share/ansible/library
```

Comment: So first I create a folder for my project, where I store the playbook. Inside this folder I create library subfolder, right? Then how  to install here a new ansible module and how to tell to ansible that I have a new module here?

Comment: No need to install - with the script in the library folder the task is now available to your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know that base ansible modules are not installed by default on devel version, which is the default installed version when you build from source.
Only few modules are present for developpment purpose.

So when you'll run your playbook it'll complain about not found module with following error message

```
couldn't resolve module/action 'xxx'
```

If you have no choice but building for source, don't forget to checkout the stable branch to install all basic ansible modules!